# Python - While loop to take user input and once terminated prints the list

Tags: python, while-loop

Below is my code

```
loop = 1
listInput = []
finalList = []

while True:
  print('Type "Done" to finish')
  listInput = input('\nEnter a word: ')
  if listInput == 'done':
      print(finalList)
      break
  else:
      finalList = listInput.split()
      loop += 1
```

I am getting the loop to work but when I terminate the while-loop it only prints the last entered word, not the whole list.

Kindly assist.
Cheers.
Python Newbee

Answer (score 0):

The line `finalList = listInput.split()` updates finalList as listInput.split().
So, if you want to stack the `listInput.split()` to the finalList, 
use `finalList += listInput.split()` instead of `finalList += listInput.split()`.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what you told it to do.  On every iteration, you destroy the previous value of `finalList` and replace it with *only* the current result.  If you want to keep them all, then you have to `append` the new word isntead of overwriting, something like this:

```
else:
    finalList.append(listInput.split())
```

I'm not entirely sure what your overall goal might be, so I won't suggest more improvements.  You didn't give your problem statement, and your coding practices aren't entirely clear; this will come with time.

Comment: [['hot'], ['cold'], ['summer'], ['winter']]

Comment: how can I have it without square brackets?

Comment: What is this comment supposed to be?  If you need to update your question, then edit the clarifications up there.  Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: It appears that this is a new question.  You may not put multiple questions into one Stack Overflow posting.